# Application windows flash instead of becoming active

Tags: windows, user-interface, microsoft-dynamics, autoit

My AutoIt script activates a Dynamics AX application based on parameters passed. I have the various AX applications open and minimized.

Most of the time the correct application (based on the `$partition` parameter) is activated and in focus so the script continues. But sometimes (maybe 1 out of 3) the application merely flashes in the task bar and does not activate and so the script cannot continue.

A .Net application calls my AutoIt script by parameters on Windows 2012 Server:

```
#include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>
#include <GuiListView.au3>

Local $partition = $CmdLine[1]
Local $axc       = $CmdLine[2]
Local $brand     = $CmdLine[3]
Local $sTerm     = $CmdLine[4]

;command line example
;GoToCustomerServicePage.exe "msl" "MSLtd" "MSUK" "LS14 6PN"

SearchForCust($partition, $axc, $brand, $sTerm)

Func SearchForCust($partition, $axc, $brand, $sTerm)
    ;Set the Title match mode
    Opt("WinTitleMatchMode", 2) ;1=start, 2=subStr, 3=exact, 4=advanced, -1 to -4=Nocase

    Local $custSer = StringUpper($partition) & "/Omnica MCR/Common/Customer Service"
    Local $exePath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Dynamics AX\60\Client\Bin\Ax32.exe \\zoom-sql2\axcshare\" & $axc & ".axc"
    Local $axTitle = "[TITLE:" & $partition & "; CLASS:AxMainFrame]"

    ; Wait 10 seconds for the window to appear.
    WinWait($axTitle, "", 10)

    ; Test if the window exists and display the results.
    If WinExists($axTitle, "") Then
    Else
        Run($exePath)
        WinWait($axTitle, "", 20)
    EndIf

    Local $hWnd = WinGetHandle($axTitle)

    WinActivate($hWnd)

    If WinActive($hWnd) Then
    Else
        WinWaitActive($hWnd, 5)
    EndIf

    ; Simulate clicking on the address bar
    Send("{F11}")

    ;Enter this into the address bar
    Send($custSer)
    Send("{ENTER}")

    ;Set the Brand
    Send($brand)
    Send("{ENTER}")

    ;send search term
    If $sTerm <> "unavailable" Then
        Send($sTerm)
        Send("{ENTER}")
    EndIf

EndFunc
```

Comment: Add a bunch of sleeps inbetween the sequences and see if it works as intended. If it's flashing orange that means that the program has been executed but never been activated (I think.) Maybe your application is processing somewhere too quickly (trying to activate the new window but it's not registered yet)

Comment: I'll give that a go and see what happens

Comment: Should `WinWaitActive($hWnd, 5)` be `WinWaitActive($hWnd,"", 5)` ?

Comment: Yes the WinWaitActive was missing a parameter, but it doesn't seem to have changed anything by adding it in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
; Test if the window exists and display the results.
If WinExists($axTitle, "") Then
    ; add here: check if the window is active - activate if not
    If Not WinActive($axTitle) Then WinActivate($axTitle)
Else
    Run($exePath)
    WinWait($axTitle, "", 20)
EndIf
```

Comment: Ok I see the logic here - so make sure the window is activated before getting the window handle.

Comment: The window handle should be retrievable without activating the window...